# controller & factory AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is a bit of a educational post. 
I am trying to understand why my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zsh2Bt7jBl1Z2mKKqlwa?p=preview) here does not work. I simply want to connect facotry to controller, and then use `ng-repeat` to import data.

I have tried several syntax but cannot  write proper implementation. 
Tahnks for you help.

**controller:**

```
   var wmapp = angular.module('wmapp' []);

  .controller('restaurantlistController', function ($scope, $rootScope, restaurantsFactory) {
    "use strict";
    $scope.restaurantList = restaurantsFactory.getRestaurants(); //call to restaurantfactory
})
```

**factory :**

```
angular.module('wmapp.factory_restaurants', [])

.factory('restaurantsFactory', function () {
    "use strict";
    var factory = {
            Restaurants : [
                {Name: 'A La Biche Au Bois', venueType: 'Restaurant ',  subCuisine: 'Italian',  subsubCuisine: 'Classic/traditional', address: '45 Avenue Ledru-Rollin', cp: '75012', city: 'Paris', country: 'France', countryCode: 'FR', itemid: 'PARIREST002', phoneNumber: '+331 43 43 34 38', website: '', lat: 48.8482040, long: 2.3706140, icon: 'img/restaurant_pointer_WMcustom_40x49_v3.png'},
                {Name: 'Allard   ', venueType: 'Restaurant ',  subCuisine: 'French',  subsubCuisine: 'Classic/traditional', address: '41, rue Saint-André des Arts', cp: '75006', city: 'Paris', country: 'France', countryCode: 'FR', itemid: 'PARIREST004', phoneNumber: '+33158002342', website: 'http://www.restaurant-allard.fr/en', lat: 48.8532490, long: 2.3409810, icon: 'img/restaurant_pointer_WMcustom_40x49_v3.png'},
                {Name: 'Ambassade d\'Auvergne', venueType: 'Restaurant ',  subCuisine: 'French',  subsubCuisine: 'Auvergne region', address: '22 Rue du Grenier Saint-Lazare', cp: '75003', city: 'Paris', country: 'France', countryCode: 'FR', itemid: 'PARIREST005', phoneNumber: '+331 42 72 31 22', website: 'http://www.ambassade-auvergne.com/', lat: 48.8631310, long: 2.3534140, icon: 'img/restaurant_pointer_WMcustom_40x49_v3.png'}

  // more restaurans



            ],
            getRestaurants : function () {
                return factory.Restaurants;
            },
        };
    return factory;

});
```

**html:**

```
  <div data-ng-controller="restaurantlistController" ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantList " href="#">
    <article class="item_frame">
      <div class="marker_left_container">
        <img class="venue_rest_marker" ng-src="{{restaurant.icon}}" />
        <span class="venu_type_text">{{restaurant.venueType}}</span>
        <span class="distance_from_user_rest">0.7 km</span>
        <span class="distance_from_user_rest2">from current location</span>
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant_details_container">
        <h1 class="restaurant_name_inlist">{{restaurant.Name}}</h1>
        <span class="restaurant_detail_inlist2">{{restaurant.subCuisine}}                            <br />

      {{restaurant.subsubCuisine}}</span>
        <span class="restaurant_address">{{restaurant.address}},                             <br />
        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_address">{{restaurant.cp}}, {{restaurant.city}}                             <br />
          <br />
        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_others">{{restaurant.phoneNumber}}                            <br />
        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_others">{{restaurant.website}}                            <br />
          <br />
        </span>
      </div>
    </article>
    <!--main article frame 1 -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there more then 4 errors mainly `semicolon , dots , module` not include errors
check this link it is working now [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/tSbRtVKYawq3081Qwqzl/preview)